# Getting an error zipfail error in swift ios

Tags: swift, unzip

Given the code below I am successfully downloading my tar.gz file but when I try unzip it I get
Error creating a file file:///Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/346A7980-8EFB-4ACE-88FC-617C9533E893/data/Containers/Data/Application/22F22B8E-2C15-4C17-B6CD-3777B66D2AAE/Documents/ : unzipFail

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
    import UIKit
    import WebKit
    import Zip
    class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
        
        var webView: WKWebView!
        
        override func loadView() {
            let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
            webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
            webView.uiDelegate = self
            view = webView
        }
        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            
            // Create destination URL
            let documentsUrl:URL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
            let destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("data.tar.gz")
  
            //Create URL to the source file you want to download
            let fileURL = URL(string: "https:/www.myurl.com/data.tar.gz")
            
            let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
         
            let request = URLRequest(url:fileURL!)
            
            let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in
                if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {
                    // Success
                    if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                        print("Successfully downloaded. Status code: \(statusCode)")
                        do {
                            try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destinationFileUrl)
                            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: destinationFileUrl)
                            let unzipDirectory = try Zip.quickUnzipFile(destinationFileUrl)
                        } catch (let writeError) {
                            print("Error creating a file \(documentsUrl) : \(writeError)")
                        }
                    
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    print("Error took place while downloading a file. Error description: %@", error?.localizedDescription);
                }
            }
            task.resume()
            
        }
```

Comment: How do you `URLSession` has finished downloading the file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the tar.gz is not supported. I used an alternative library